# failed to open stream: No such file or directory Codeignter

Tags: php, codeigniter, csv

I'm trying to upload data from a csv file into my sql server database.

So I created this csv reader library :

```
<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class CSVReader
{

    var $fields;
    /** columns names retrieved after parsing */
    var $separator = ';';
    /** separator used to explode each line */
    var $enclosure = '"';
    /** enclosure used to decorate each field */

    var $max_row_size = 4096;
    /** maximum row size to be used for decoding */

    function parse_file($p_Filepath)
    {

        $file = fopen($p_Filepath, 'r');
        $this->fields = fgetcsv($file, $this->max_row_size, $this->separator, $this->enclosure);
        $keys_values = explode(',', $this->fields[0]);

        $content    =   array();
        $keys   =   $this->escape_string($keys_values);

        $i  =   1;
        while (($row = fgetcsv($file, $this->max_row_size, $this->separator, $this->enclosure)) != false) {
            if ($row != null) { // skip empty lines
                $values =   explode(',', $row[0]);
                if (count($keys) == count($values)) {
                    $arr    =   array();
                    $new_values =   array();
                    $new_values =   $this->escape_string($values);
                    for ($j = 0; $j < count($keys); $j++) {
                        if ($keys[$j] != "") {
                            $arr[$keys[$j]] =   $new_values[$j];
                        }
                    }

                    $content[$i] =   $arr;
                    $i++;
                }
            }
        }
        fclose($file);
        return $content;
    }

    function escape_string($data)
    {
        $result =   array();
        foreach ($data as $row) {
            $result[]   =   str_replace('"', '', $row);
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
?>
```

and I added this part of JS code to send my file from view to controller :

```
$("#form").on('submit', (function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: "../Commande/sendToIncadeaWithFile",
        type: "POST",
        data: new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function() {

        },
        error: function(e) {

        }
    });
}));
```

then I'm trying to start the coding of my data retrieving part from the file so I can send them to the model in order to insert them inside the database.

I just started by trying to see if the data are retrieved correctly by doing this :

```
<?php
if ($_FILES['file']) {

    $fileName = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    var_dump($_FILES["file"]["size"]);
    $cofing['upload_path'] = './upload/';
    $cofing['allowed_types'] = 'csv';
    $this->load->library('upload', $cofing);

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('file')) {
        echo $this->upload->display_errors();
    } else {
        $data = $this->upload->data();

        $result =   $this->csvreader->parse_file($fileName);
        var_dump($result);
    }
}
?>
```

but I'm getting this error:

> failed to open stream: No such file or directory

which is pointing the `fopen` instruction.

Can you help me solve this?

Comment: and did you `var_dump($fileName);`? is it output the correct path?

Comment: the files are uploaded inside an upload folder that I've created inside my application folder so it's showing me the file name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you are not pointing to full path (including the folder)

try

```
<?php
 $data = $this->upload->data();
    //$csvFile=FCPATH."upload/".$fileName; //php way (uploaded filepath and filename )
  $csvFile=$data['full_path']; //codeigniter way
  $result =   $this->csvreader->parse_file($csvFile);

?>
```